# MPI fail to compile benchmark (undefined reference to `MPI_Type_extent')

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, mpi

I have a problem compiling a benchmark.

How I compile:

> make MPI_HOME=/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2/

makefile:

```
SRC_C = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ_C = $(subst .c$,.o,$(SRC_C))
EXE_C = $(subst .c$,,$(SRC_C))

SRC_F = $(wildcard *.f)
OBJ_F = $(subst .f$,.o,$(SRC_F))
EXE_F = $(subst .f$,,$(SRC_F))
CFLAGS = -g

MPI_HOME=
CC=$(MPI_HOME)/bin/mpicc
F90=$(MPI_HOME)/bin/mpif90

all: all-c all-f

all-c: $(OBJ_C)
        $(foreach t,$(EXE_C),$(CC) -o $(t) $(t).o -lm;)

$(OBJ_C): %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(EXE_C): $(OBJ_C)
        $(CC) -o $* $@

all-f: $(OBJ_F)
        $(foreach t,$(EXE_F),$(F90) -o $(t) $(t).o;)

$(OBJ_F): %.o: %.f
        $(F90) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(EXE_F): $(OBJ_F)
        $(F90) -o $* $@

clean:
        @rm -f $(OBJ_F) $(OBJ_C) $(EXE_C) $(EXE_F)
```

after running the makefile

```
make MPI_HOME=/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2/

makefile doing this:                                                                                                                                
/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2//bin/mpicc -c -g ctxalloc.c
-o ctxalloc.o

/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2//bin/mpicc -c -g un_contiguous.c -o un_contiguous.o

/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2//bin/mpicc -c -g allgather_fail.c -o allgather_fail.o

/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2//bin/mpicc -o allgather_fail allgather_fail.o -lm;

/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2//bin/mpicc -o un_contiguous un_contiguous.o -lm;

 /usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-4.0.0rc2//bin/mpicc -o ctxalloc ctxalloc.o -lm;
```

output:

> un_contiguous.o: In function test_allgatherv:
>   /mswg2/E2E/Regression_logs/BabyZeusCluster/MPI/4.5-0.0.9.0_OFED/hpc_tests/mpi/misc/un_contiguous.c:236:
>   undefined reference to MPI_Type_extent

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Type_extent()` has been deprecated and removed from the MPI standard quite a while ago.

Starting from Open MPI 4, these removed subroutines are no more build by default.

Your best option is to modernize your code (and use `MPI_Type_get_extent()` instead.

If this is not an option (a 3rd party binary only library is using this for example), then you have to reinstall Open MPI and `configure --with-mpi1-compatibility ...`.
(You might want to notify your vendor too since this workaround might be removed from Open MPI 5)